# Bash script from Codesourcery arm-2011.03 can't find grep or sed

Tags: bash, path

I'm trying to run the CodeSourcery arm-2011.03.42 BASH script in Ubuntu 12.04.  At the top of the script is the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

But, when I execute it, I get the following errors:

*line 140: grep: command not found*

*line 140: sed: command not found*

I can run both grep and sed from the command line, but not in the script.

Here's what line 140 look like

```
env_var_list=$(export | \
    grep '^declare -x ' | \
    sed -e 's/^declare -x //' -e 's/=.*//')
```

If I change the first line to

```
#!/bin/sh
```

I get the following error:

*Line 51: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")*

Here's what Line 51 looks like

```
check_pipe() {
    local -a status=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}")  #<-- Line 51
    local limit=$1
    local ix
```

The `#<-- Line 51` actually doesn't appear in the shell script.  I just added it to this post for clarity.

I've tried dos2unix and a number of other things, but I just can't win.  I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: '#! /usr/bin/env bash' should probably be '#!/usr/bin/env bash' no space between #! and /usr/bin/env

Comment: @Cfreak Tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AntonioD Tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: There's a bug in the script that mangles the `PATH` variable. Post the content of the script or a link to it and I can probably tell you where.

Comment: Command substitution was invoked in a subshell, there must be something thant tampered with the $PATH variable in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed this line in the script

```
pushenvvar PATH /usr/local/tools/gcc-4.3.3/bin
```

to

```
pushenvvar PATH /usr/local/tools/gcc-4.3.3/bin:/bin
```

and it seems to work now.

Comment: Add `/usr/bin` as well. There's probably a bug in the `pushenvvar` function, which this works around.

Comment: The lesson is that $PATH in your interactive shell is not necessarily the same $PATH as in any given point in a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Shell script must be bash as arrays don't exist in sh.

Check your PATH evironment variable, and the path of grep and sed /bin normally.

Comment: I tried "sudo bash myscript.sh" and I still get the "command not found" errors.  I can run grep and sed from the command line, so they must be in my path, and must have the correct access.

Comment: “Check your PATH evironment variable”: right, but the problem is clearly that the script itself mangles it.

Answer (score -1):

Ther might be several possiable reasons.

1. As @AntonioD pointed out, there must not be any space between '#!' and '/usr/bin/env' at the begining of the file.
2. The `grep` and `sed` command does not exists in your $PATH, checkout your `/bin` and `/user/bin` to see if they are existed, or run `which grep` and `which sed` in your shell.
3. If `grep` and `sed` are indeed existed, you need to make sure they have right access.They should be accessable and executable, in general, this should not happen.
4. You must not using `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/usr/bin/evn` or `#!/bin/bash`, because that would cause the shell run in POSIX compatible mode in which most of bash advanced features such as arrays are not functional.

If all of above are not the case, then it is really weird.

Comment: 1.  Doesn't work.  2,3.  grep and sed can both be run from the command line, but don't work within the shell script.  4. tried "sudo bash myscript.sh" and I still get the "command not found" errors.

Comment: None of this will help. 1 is flat wrong, a space after `#!` is fine. 2 and 3 are extremely unlikely and would cause the system to not even boot. 4 is wrong, `#! /usr/bin/env bash` (the way it originally was) is fine and doesn't cause bash to run in a mode that disables arrays.

Comment: @Gilles I am not sure if you understood my words above correctly. I admit my mistake about 1, but 2 and 3 is just a check to make sure all the things are correct and doing nothing to the system, why would you think it will break the system? About 4, I am not quite sure what is wrong about using `#!/bin/sh` will make shell run under POSIX compatible mode?

Comment: @TechliveZheng Look at the number of calls to `grep` and `sed` in the boot scripts (`/etc/init/*`, `/etc/init.d/*`). If they weren't working properly, so many things would break that you'd notice. About 4, using `#!/bin/sh` would not work (`/bin/sh` is dash on Ubuntu), but `#! /usr/bin/env bash`, which Verax indicated was the shebang line, is fine. Bash doesn't disable arrays in posix mode, by the way, but something else in the script might break with bash in posix mode.

Comment: @Gilles About 2 and 3, I just point it out that they should be checked to make sure and these steps do nothing to the system, yes, initial scripts need `sed` and `grep` working properly, but something might happened after booting like being hacked or damaged on purpose, and how often do you reboot a *nix box, I barely do that. About 4, I made myself clear in the original post that `#!/bin/sh` should not be used, maybe my last sentence make you confused, if so, sorry about that, I am not a native English speaker. About 1, it is okay with a space, but I am not sure it is a good habbit.